# WebGL: 2D Fragment Shader With Dynamic Data

Tags: glsl, webgl, fragment-shader

I am working on a top-down 2D HTML5 game that uses pixel-by-pixel area sampling and manipulation to create a wave rippling effect. I got this up and running in JavaScript, but the performance was iffy on FireFox and completely unacceptable on Chrome. I considered porting my entire prototype to a platform with better performance but learned about GL shaders along the way.

I thought it would be simple enough to adapt my algorithm to a GL fragment shader. I am on my fourth consecutive day trying to get my shader to produce any output whatsoever. I've done my very best to adapt solutions from other questions and tutorials to what I'm doing, but none of them are quite close enough to my specific needs.

First, I'll present an overview of what I need to happen conceptually. Then I'll provide code and explain the approach that I've tried to take so far. I'm willing to start from scratch if I can just make sense of what I need to do.

The algorithm for the wave effect works as described [here](https://www.gamedev.net/resources/_/technical/graphics-programming-and-theory/the-water-effect-explained-r915). It involves rendering a new image from a source image by displacing certain pixels based on wave height data for each pixel, stored in two matrices with a corresponding entry for each pixel in the image. One is used as the current state of the water, and the other stores the results of the previous frame to use for calculating the current.

Per frame: waveMapCurrent is calculated by averaging values waveMapPrevious

Per pixel: displacement is calculated from the height in waveMapCurrent and (in psuedocode) `newPixelData[current] = sourcePixelData[current+displacement]`

At a minimum, I need my fragment shader to be able to access the data from the current wave height matrix and the image to use as a source. If I understand things correctly, it would be the most beneficial for performance to minimize the number of times I pass new data to the GL pipeline and instead perform the wave height calculations within a shader, but I can alternatively do the calculations in my script and pass the updated version of the wave height matrix to the fragment shader each frame.

Before I can even think about what the fragment shader is doing, though, there is the task of setting up an object to actually draw fragments to. As far as I can tell, this requires setting up vertices to represent the canvas and setting them to the corners of the canvas to get WebGL to render it as a flat, 2D image, but that seems unintuitive. I either need to render this to an image to use as a background texture or initialize a second canvas and set the background of the first to be transparent (which is what I've tried to do in my code below). If there is any way to get the fragment shader to run and simply render its output with each fragment corresponding 1:1 with the pixels of the canvas/image, that would be sublime, but I assume nothing with GLSL.

What I've tried to do is pack the current wave height matrix as a texture and send it in as a uniform sampler2D. In its current state, my code runs, but WebGL tells me that active texture 1, which is my wave height matrix packed as a texture, is incomplete and that it's minification/magnification filtering is not set to NEAREST, even though I have tried to explicitly set it to NEAREST. I have no idea how to debug it any further, because WebGL is citing my call to gl.drawElements as the source of the error.

That is as intelligently as I can describe this. Here is what I have:

```
    ws.glProgram = function(gl, tex) {

    var flExt = gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float");
    ws.program = gl.createProgram();
    var vertShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    var fragShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    var vertSrc = [

    "attribute vec4 position;",

    "void main(void) {",
        "gl_Position = position;",
    "}"

    ]

    var fragSrc = [
    "precision highp float;",

    "uniform sampler2D canvasTex;",
    "uniform sampler2D dataTex;",

    "uniform vec2 mapSize;",
    "uniform float dispFactor;",
    "uniform float lumFactor;",

    "void main(void) {",


        "vec2 mapCoord = vec2(gl_FragCoord.x+1.5, gl_FragCoord.y+1.5);",
        "float wave = texture2D(dataTex, mapCoord).r;",
        "float displace = wave*dispFactor;",

        "if (displace < 0.0) {",
            "displace = displace+1.0;",
        "}",

        "vec2 srcCoord = vec2(gl_FragCoord.x+displace,gl_FragCoord.y+displace);",

        "if (srcCoord.x < 0.0) {",
            "srcCoord.x = 0.0;",
        "}",
        "else if (srcCoord.x > mapSize.x-2.0) {",
            "srcCoord.x = mapSize.x-2.0;",
        "}",

        "if (srcCoord.y < 0.0) {",
            "srcCoord.y = 0.0;",
        "}",
        "else if (srcCoord.y > mapSize.y-2.0) {",
            "srcCoord.y = mapSize.y-2.0;",
        "}",

        "float lum = wave*lumFactor;",
        "if (lum > 40.0) { lum = 40.0; }",
        "else if (lum < -40.0) { lum = -40.0; }",

        "gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);", // Fragment Shader is not producing output

        /*"gl_FragColor = texture2D(canvasTex, srcCoord);",
        "gl_FragColor.r = gl_FragColor.r + lum;",
        "gl_FragColor.g = gl_FragColor.g + lum;",
        "gl_FragColor.b = gl_FragColor.b + lum;",*/

    "}"];

    vertSrc = vertSrc.join('\n');
    fragSrc = fragSrc.join('\n');

    gl.shaderSource(vertShader, vertSrc);
    gl.compileShader(vertShader);
    gl.attachShader(ws.program, vertShader);

    gl.shaderSource(fragShader, fragSrc);
    gl.compileShader(fragShader);
    gl.attachShader(ws.program, fragShader);

    console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertShader));

    gl.linkProgram(ws.program);
    gl.useProgram(ws.program);

    // Vertex Data for rendering surface
    var vertices = [ 0,0,0, 1,0,0,
                     0,1,0, 1,1,0 ];
    var indices = [  0,1,2, 0,2,3 ];

    ws.program.vertices = new Float32Array(vertices);
    ws.program.indices = new Float32Array(indices);

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, ws.program.vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    var iBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ws.program.indices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // Send texture data from tex to WebGL
    var canvasTex = gl.createTexture();
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE2);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, canvasTex);

    // Non-Power-of-Two Texture Dimensions
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex.imageData);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(ws.program, "canvasTex"), 2);

    // Send empty wave map to WebGL
    ws.activeWaveMap = new Float32Array((ws.width+2)*(ws.height+2));
    ws.dataPointerGL = gl.createTexture();
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, ws.dataPointerGL);

    // Non-Power-of-Two Texture Dimensions
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, ws.width+2,ws.height+2,0, gl.LUMINANCE, gl.FLOAT, ws.activeWaveMap);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(ws.program, "dataTex"), 1);

    // Numeric Uniforms
    gl.uniform2f(gl.getUniformLocation(ws.program, "mapSize"), ws.width+2,ws.height+2);
    gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(ws.program, "dispFactor"), ws.dispFactor);
    gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(ws.program, "lumFactor"), ws.lumFactor);

    return ws.program;

}

    ws.render = function(gl, moves, canvas) {
    //canvas.clear();
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // specify gl.clearColor?

    for (g=0, fl=0; g < ws.tempWaveMap.length; g++) {
        for (b=0; b < ws.tempWaveMap[g].length; b++) {
            ws.tempWaveMap[g][b] = ws.activeWaveMap[fl];
            fl += 1;
        }
    }

    for (j=0; j < moves.length; j++) {
        ws.setWave(moves[j],ws.tempWaveMap);
    }

    for (x=1; x <= ws.width; x++) {
        for (y=1; y <= ws.height; y++) {
            ws.resolveWaves(ws.inactiveWaveMap, ws.tempWaveMap, x,y);
        }
    }

    for (g=0, fl=0; g < ws.inactiveWaveMap.length; g++) {
        for (b=0; b < ws.inactiveWaveMap[g].length; b++) {
            ws.outgoingWaveMap[fl] = ws.inactiveWaveMap[g][b];
            ws.inactiveWaveMap[g][b] = ws.tempWaveMap[g][b];
            fl += 1;
        }
    }

    ws.activeWaveMap.set(ws.outgoingWaveMap);

    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, ws.width+2,ws.height+2,0, gl.LUMINANCE, gl.FLOAT, ws.activeWaveMap);

    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, ws.program.indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
}
```

**Update:** I've managed to set up my 2D drawing surface using corner vertices. (The tutorial [here](https://capnramses.github.io/opengl/webgl_starter.html) was very helpful for getting my foundations in using VAO's.) Now I am trying to work out the best way to upload, store, and manipulate my data.

**SOLVED:** I got my code working, thanks to gman. The wave behavior itself still needs debugging, but everything in terms of the GL pipeline is running as it should. In addition to strange wave behavior, the game lags every several seconds for just a moment and then resumes at normal speed. Performance tests show that non-incremental garbage collection is the cause, and this doesn't happen when the water effect is disabled, so it's definitely something in my code, probably the array `newIndices` being freshly initialized every frame, but I'm not sure. Unless it's something to do with GL's behavior, it's beyond the scope of this question.

Here is the relevant code. All you really need to know outside of what's here is that the GL context, vertex shader for drawing the 2D surface, and VAO are passed in from another object, and that object runs the `render` function every frame.

```
function waterStage(gl, vao, vShader) {

var ws = new Object();

ws.width = game.world.width; ws.height = game.world.height;

// Initialize Background Texture
ws.img = game.make.bitmapData(ws.width, ws.height);

ws.img.fill(0,10,40);
ws.img.ctx.strokeStyle = "#5050FF";
ws.img.ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ws.img.ctx.moveTo(0,0);
for (y=0; y < ws.height; y+=10) {
    ws.img.ctx.beginPath();
    ws.img.ctx.moveTo(0,y);
    ws.img.ctx.lineTo(ws.width,y);
    ws.img.ctx.closePath();
    ws.img.ctx.stroke();
}

ws.img.update();

gl.flExt = gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float");

gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);

// Source Image
ws.srcTexture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, ws.srcTexture);

    // Enable all texture sizes
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, ws.img.imageData);

delete ws.img;

// Map Textures

ws.clearProgram = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(ws.clearProgram, vShader);

var clearSrc = [
    "precision highp float;",

    "void main(void) {",
        "gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);",
    "}"
];

clearSrc = clearSrc.join("\n");
var clearShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(clearShader, clearSrc);
gl.compileShader(clearShader);
gl.attachShader(ws.clearProgram, clearShader);
gl.linkProgram(ws.clearProgram);

ws.mapTextures = [];
ws.frameBuffers = [];
for (t=0; t < 2; t++) {

    var map = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, map);

        // Enable all texture sizes
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    // Initialize empty texture of the same size as the canvas
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, ws.width, ws.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

    ws.mapTextures.push(map);

    var fbo = gl.createFramebuffer()
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, map, 0);

    ws.frameBuffers.push(fbo);

    gl.useProgram(ws.clearProgram);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fbo); // Set output to new map
    gl.vao_ext.bindVertexArrayOES(vao);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}

gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);

// Blank texture to be copied to in render()
ws.copyTexture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, ws.copyTexture);

    // Enable all texture sizes
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, ws.width, ws.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

// Blank texture for entering new wave values through GL
ws.nwTexture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, ws.nwTexture);

    // Enable all texture sizes
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, ws.width, ws.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

ws.newWaves = new Array(ws.width*ws.height);

ws.nwProgram = gl.createProgram();
ws.mapProgram = gl.createProgram();
ws.displaceProgram = gl.createProgram();

gl.attachShader(ws.nwProgram, vShader);
gl.attachShader(ws.mapProgram, vShader);
gl.attachShader(ws.displaceProgram, vShader);

var nwSrc = [
    "precision highp float;",

    "uniform sampler2D newWaves;",
    "uniform sampler2D previous;",
    "uniform vec2 size;",

    "void main(void) {",
        "vec2 texCoord = vec2((gl_FragCoord.x/size.x),(gl_FragCoord.y/size.y));",
        "float nw = texture2D(newWaves, texCoord).r;",

        "if (nw == 0.0) {",
            "gl_FragColor = texture2D(previous, texCoord);",
        "}",
        "else {",
            "float current = texture2D(previous, texCoord).r;",
            "nw = float(current+nw);",
            "gl_FragColor = vec4(nw, nw, nw, 1.0);",
        "}",
    "}"
]

nwSrc = nwSrc.join("\n");
var nwShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(nwShader, nwSrc);
gl.compileShader(nwShader);

console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(nwShader));

gl.attachShader(ws.nwProgram, nwShader);
gl.linkProgram(ws.nwProgram);

var mapSrc = [
    "precision highp float;",

    "uniform sampler2D previous;",
    "uniform sampler2D current;",
    "uniform vec2 size;",
    "uniform float damper;",

    "void main(void) {",
        "vec4 surrounding;",
        "vec2 texCoord = vec2((gl_FragCoord.x/size.x),(gl_FragCoord.y/size.y));",

        "float active = texture2D(current, texCoord).r-0.5;",

        "vec2 shifted = vec2(((gl_FragCoord.x-1.0)/size.x),texCoord.y);", // x-1

        "if (gl_FragCoord.x == 0.0) {",
            "surrounding.x = 0.0;",
        "}",
        "else {",
            "surrounding.x = texture2D(previous, shifted).r-0.5;",
        "}",

        "shifted = vec2(((gl_FragCoord.x+1.0)/size.x),texCoord.y);", // x+1

        "if (gl_FragCoord.x == size.x-1.0) {",
            "surrounding.z = 0.0;",
        "}",
        "else {",
            "surrounding.z = texture2D(previous, shifted).r-0.5;",
        "}",

        "shifted = vec2(texCoord.x,((gl_FragCoord.y-1.0)/size.y));", // y-1

        "if (gl_FragCoord.y == 0.0) {",
            "surrounding.y = 0.0;",
        "}",
        "else {",
            "surrounding.y = texture2D(previous, shifted).r-0.5;",
        "}",

        "shifted = vec2(texCoord.x,((gl_FragCoord.y+1.0)/size.y));", // y+1

        "if (gl_FragCoord.y == size.y-1.0) {",
            "surrounding.w = 0.0;",
        "}",
        "else {",
            "surrounding.w = texture2D(previous, shifted).r-0.5;",
        "}",

        "active = ((surrounding.x+surrounding.y+surrounding.z+surrounding.w)/2.0)-active;",
        "active = active-(active/damper);",
        "gl_FragColor = vec4(active+0.5, active+0.5, active+0.5, 1.0);",
        // "gl_FragColor = texture2D(current, vec2(gl_FragCoord.x/size.x),(gl_FragCoord.y/size.y));",
    "}"
];


mapSrc = mapSrc.join("\n");
var mapShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(mapShader, mapSrc);
gl.compileShader(mapShader);

console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(mapShader));

gl.attachShader(ws.mapProgram, mapShader);
gl.linkProgram(ws.mapProgram);

var displaceSrc = [
    "precision highp float;",

    "uniform sampler2D current;",
    "uniform sampler2D srcImg;",
    "uniform vec2 size;",
    "uniform float dspFactor;",
    "uniform float lumFactor;",

    "void main(void) {",

        "vec2 texCoord = vec2((gl_FragCoord.x/size.x),(gl_FragCoord.y/size.y));",

        "float wave = texture2D(current, texCoord).r-0.5;",
        "float displacement = wave * dspFactor * 1.5;",

        "if (displacement == 0.0) {",
            "gl_FragColor = texture2D(srcImg, texCoord);",
        "}",
        "else {",

            "if (displacement < 0.0) {",
                "displacement = displacement + 1.0;",
            "}",

            "float lum = wave * lumFactor;",
            "if (lum > 0.16) { lum = 0.16; }",
            "else if (lum < -0.16) { lum = -0.16; }",

            "float dspX = (gl_FragCoord.x+displacement);",
            "float dspY = (gl_FragCoord.y+displacement);",

            "if (dspX < 0.0) { dspX = 0.0; }",
            "else if (dspX >= size.x) { dspX = size.x-1.0; }",
            "if (dspY < 0.0) { dspY = 0.0; }",
            "else if (dspY >= size.y) { dspY = size.y-1.0; }",

            "vec2 srcCoord = vec2((dspX/size.x),(dspY/size.y));",

            // Just for testing
            //"gl_FragColor = texture2D(current, vec2((gl_FragCoord.x/size.x),(gl_FragCoord.y/size.y)));",

            "vec4 newColor = texture2D(srcImg, srcCoord);", // srcCoord
            "gl_FragColor.r = newColor.r+lum;",
            "gl_FragColor.g = newColor.g+lum;",
            "gl_FragColor.b = newColor.b+lum;",
        "}",
    "}"

];

displaceSrc = displaceSrc.join("\n");
var displaceShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(displaceShader, displaceSrc);
gl.compileShader(displaceShader);

console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(displaceShader));

gl.attachShader(ws.displaceProgram, displaceShader);
gl.linkProgram(ws.displaceProgram);

ws.render = function(gl, vao, moves) {
    // Calculate wave values as texture data, then render to screen with displacement fragment shader

    if (moves.length > 0) {

        for (x=0, len=ws.width*ws.height; x < len; x++) {
            ws.newWaves[x] = 0;
        }

        var newIndices = [];
        for (m=0; m < moves.length; m++) {
            newIndices.push(moves[m].y*ws.width + moves[m].x);
        }

        for (i=0; i < newIndices.length; i++) {
            ws.newWaves[newIndices[i]] = moves[i].magnitude/1;
        }

        gl.useProgram(ws.nwProgram);

        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, ws.nwTexture);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, ws.width, ws.height, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, gl.FLOAT, new Float32Array(ws.newWaves));
        gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(ws.nwProgram, "newWaves"), 0);

        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, ws.copyTexture);
        gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(ws.nwProgram, "previous"), 1);

        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, ws.frameBuffers[0]); // Set output to previous map texture [0]
        gl.copyTexImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 0, 0, ws.width, ws.height, 0); // Copy mapTextures[0] into copyTexture

        gl.uniform2f(gl.getUniformLocation(ws.nwProgram, "size"), ws.width, ws.height);

        gl.vao_ext.bindVertexArrayOES(vao);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    }

    // Map Texture Manipulation
    gl.useProgram(ws.mapProgram);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, ws.mapTextures[0]);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(ws.mapProgram, "previous"), 0);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, ws.copyTexture);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(ws.mapProgram, "current"), 1);

    gl.uniform2f(gl.getUniformLocation(ws.mapProgram, "size"), ws.width, ws.height);
    gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(ws.mapProgram, "damper"), 1000);

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, ws.frameBuffers[1]); // Set output to current map texture [1]
    gl.copyTexImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 0, 0, ws.width, ws.height, 0); // Copy mapTextures[1] into copyTexture
    gl.vao_ext.bindVertexArrayOES(vao);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    // Output Texture Manipulation
    gl.useProgram(ws.displaceProgram);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, ws.mapTextures[1]);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(ws.displaceProgram, "current"), 0);
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, ws.srcTexture);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(ws.displaceProgram, "srcImg"), 1);
    gl.uniform2f(gl.getUniformLocation(ws.displaceProgram, "size"), ws.width, ws.height);
    gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(ws.displaceProgram, "dspFactor"), 20);
    gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(ws.displaceProgram, "lumFactor"), 0.5);

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null); // Output to canvas
    gl.vao_ext.bindVertexArrayOES(vao);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    ws.mapTextures.sort(function(a,b) { return 1; });
    ws.frameBuffers.sort(function(a,b) { return 1; });
}
```

Comment: Just some pointers: in addition to the minification filter you also want to set the magnification filter to `NEAREST`. If you want to fill the canvas with the output you'll want to provide your vertex coordinates in NDC space -1 ... 1 not 0...1. Executable code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: and set the `viewport`

Comment: @LJᛃ I'm not sure I could isolate a snippet that would run if separated from the rest of the game loop. The ws object is taking its input and its GL context from another object, StageLoader, which accesses positional data from active game objects and updates during the game engine's update() method. I could create a basic model of it, though, if that would help

Comment: @LJᛃ Also I did get the 2D surface displaying correctly, so now it's just about the data streaming

Comment: still incomplete texture? have you set the magfilter to nearest aswell ?

Comment: @LJᛃ Oh, I hadn't tried to run that part of the program again. I disabled it while I was getting the 2D surface working and changed some code around, so I'll have to get that part matching. I'll see what it does now and report back

Comment: @LJᛃ You're right. Incomplete texture message went away. I have some serious reworking to do before the fragment shader behaves correctly (specifically, I'm concerned that my float values might be getting normalized when they're passed in), but I believe my data is in there. Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to pass on [these tutorials](http://webglfundamentals.org) only because you claim you've read a bunch of stuff but if you didn't know that WebGL only cares about clipspace coordinates than you it seems like you might have missed some very fundamental things about WebGL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't read the contents of the canvas in WebGL from a shader so instead you need to create a texture and attach that texture to a framebuffer (a framebuffer is just a collection of attachments). This way you can render to the texture and use the result in other renders

Next up, [textures, at least in WebGL 1, are always referenced by texture coordinates which go from 0 to 1](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html) so this code doesn't make much sense

```
  vec2 mapCoord = vec2(gl_FragCoord.x+1.5, gl_FragCoord.y+1.5);
  float wave = texture2D(dataTex, mapCoord).r;
```

`gl_FragCoord` is not in texture coordinates it's in absolute destination pixels meaning if you rectangle in the middle of the screen `gl_FragCoord` will have the dest pixel coordinates (not starting at 0). As for the +1.5, 1.5 in any direction in texture coordinates is 1.5 * the width or height of the texture.

If you want to look one pixel left or right you need to know the size of the texture.

One pixel unit in texture coordinates is `1 / width` in across and `1 / height` down. So in other words, if you have some texture coordinate that references a pixel

```
 vec2 texcoord = vec2(0.5, 0.5);  // center of texture
```

And you want to get one pixel to the right it's

```
 vec2 onePixelRight = texcoord + vec2(1.0 / textureWidth, 0);
```

The width of a `textureWidth` is not passed in in WebGL1 so you'll have to make a uniform and pass it in yourself.

You can see [an example of rendering to a texture through a framebuffer and reading from nearby pixels here](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing-continued.html)

Looking at the link you posted you need 4 textures

- 1 texture is your image (I guess you want to displace this?)
- 1 texture is your current wave
- 1 texture is your previous wave
- 1 texture is your next wave

And you need 3 framebuffers. One for each wave

- Each frame

  - bind framebuffer that uses next wave so you'll be rendering to next wave
  - render using shader that computes current wave from previous wave
  - bind null for framebuffer so you'll be rendering to canvas
  - render using shader that uses current wave texture as displacement of image texture
  - swap newWave to current, current to prev, prev to next

    note: (This just means changing variables in the code, no data needs to be moved)

Here's some code based on the original. Since I can't run the original I have no idea what it's supposed to look like.

```js
function main() {
  var width = 256;
  var height = 256;
  var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
  var flExt = gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float");
  // you should always check for this unless you want confused users
  if (!flExt) {
    alert("no floating point textures available on your system");
    return;
  }

  // the algoritm from the article requires all textures and the canvas
  // to be the same size
  gl.canvas.width = width;
  gl.canvas.height = height;


  // template literals or script tags are way easier than arrays of strings
  var vertSrc = `
attribute vec4 position;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = position;
}
`;

  var waveFragSrc = `
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D currentSourceMap;
uniform sampler2D previousResultMap;

uniform float damp;
uniform vec2 textureSize;

void main(void) {
  vec2 onePixel = 1. / textureSize;

  // this only works because we're drawing a quad the size of the texture
  // normally I'd pass in texture coords
  vec2 xy = gl_FragCoord.xy / textureSize;

  vec4 n = 
    (texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(-1, 0)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(-2, 0)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(+1, 0)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(+2, 0)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2( 0,-1)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2( 0,-2)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2( 0,+1)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2( 0,+2)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(-1,-1)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(+1,-1)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(-1,+1)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(+1,+1))
    ) / 6.0 - texture2D(previousResultMap, xy);
   gl_FragColor = n - n / damp;

}

`;

  // need another shader to draw the result texture to the screen
  var displaceFragSrc = `
precision highp float;

uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform sampler2D waveMap;
uniform sampler2D backgroundImage;
uniform float rIndex;

// this code assumes the wavemap and the image and the destination
// are all the same resolution
void main() {
   vec2 onePixel = 1. / resolution;

   // this only works because we're drawing a quad the size of the texture
   // normally I'd pass in texture coords
   vec2 xy = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution;

   float xDiff = floor(texture2D(waveMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(1, 0)) -
                       texture2D(waveMap, xy)).r;
   float yDiff = floor(texture2D(waveMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(0, 1)) -
                       texture2D(waveMap, xy)).r;

   float xAngle = atan( xDiff );
   float xRefraction = asin( sin( xAngle ) / rIndex );
   float xDisplace = floor( tan( xRefraction ) * xDiff );

   float yAngle = atan( yDiff );
   float yRefraction = asin( sin( yAngle ) / rIndex );
   float yDisplace = floor( tan( yRefraction ) * yDiff );

   if (xDiff < 0.) {
      // { Current position is higher - Clockwise rotation }
      if (yDiff < 0.) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(
            backgroundImage, xy + onePixel * vec2(-xDisplace, -yDisplace));
   } else {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(
             backgroundImage, xy + onePixel * vec2(-xDisplace, +yDisplace));
      }
   } else {
      // { Current position is lower - Counterclockwise rotation }
      if (yDiff < 0.) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(backgroundImage, vec2(+xDisplace, -yDisplace));
   } else {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(backgroundImage, vec2(+xDisplace, +yDisplace));
      }
   }
}

`;

  // use some boilerplate. I'm too lazy to type all the code for looking
  // up uniforms and setting them when a tiny piece of code can hide all
  // that for me. Look up the library if it's not clear that `setUniforms`
  // does lots of `gl.uniformXXX` etc...

  // also Use **MUST** look up the attribute locations or assign them with
  // gl.bindAttribLocation **BEFORE** linking otherwise your code
  // is not portable and may not match across programs. This boilerplate
  // calls gl.bindAttributeLocation for the names passed in the 3rd argument
  var waveProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vertSrc, waveFragSrc], ["position"]);
  var displaceProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vertSrc, displaceFragSrc], ["position"]);

  var positionLocation = 0; // see above

  // Vertex Data for rendering surface
  // no reason for 3d points when drawing 2d
  // Not using indices. It's several more lines of un-needed code
  var vertices = new Float32Array([
    -1,-1,  1,-1, -1,1,
     1,-1, -1, 1,  1,1,
  ]);

  var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  // Send texture data from tex to WebGL
  var imageTex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, imageTex);

  // since we don't have an image lets make one with a canvas 2d.
  var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
  ctx.canvas.width = width;
  ctx.canvas.height = height;
  for (var y = 0; y < width; y += 16) {
    for (var x = 0; x < height; x += 16) {
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + x / width * 256 +
                      ","    + y / height * 256 +
                      ","    + (x / 16 + y / 16) % 2 * 255 +
                      ")";
      ctx.fillRect(x, y, 16, 16);
    }
  }

  // Non-Power-of-Two Texture Dimensions
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, ctx.canvas);


  // make some data for the wave
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(1,1,1)";
  ctx.lineWidth = 30;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2,
          ctx.canvas.width / 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.stroke();

  // You can NOT use any kind of filtering on FLOAT textures unless
  // you check for and enable OES_texture_float_linear. Note that
  // no mobile devices support it as of 2017/1

  // create 3 wave textures and 3 framebuffers, prevs, current, and next
  var waves = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    var tex = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    // Non-Power-of-Two Texture Dimensions
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, ctx.canvas);

    var fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D,
                            tex, 0);
    if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) !== gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
      alert("can not render to floating point textures");
      return;
    }
    waves.push({ texture: tex, framebuffer: fb });
  }

  function render() {
    var previousWave = waves[0];
    var currentWave = waves[1];
    var nextWave = waves[2];

    // while you're only drawing 1 thing at the moment if you want to draw
    // more than one you'll need to set attributes before each draw if
    // data changes

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    // draw to next wave
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, nextWave.framebuffer);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);

    gl.useProgram(waveProgramInfo.program);

    // pass current and previous textures to shader
    twgl.setUniforms(waveProgramInfo, {
      currentSourceMap: currentWave.texture,
      previousResultMap: previousWave.texture,
      textureSize: [width, height],
      damp: 4,
    });

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    // draw to canvas
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    gl.useProgram(displaceProgramInfo.program);

    // pass in the next wave to the displacement shader
    twgl.setUniforms(displaceProgramInfo, {
      waveMap: nextWave.texture,
      backgroundImage: imageTex,
      resolution: [gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height],
      rIndex: 4,
    });

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    // swap the buffers. 
    var temp = waves[0];
    waves[0] = waves[1];
    waves[1] = waves[2];
    waves[2] = temp;
    
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/2.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

The effect is very old school as it's pixel based and lots of integers whereas shaders use floating point. I get the impression the exact algorithm is not really a good match for shaders. Or rather you could get much better results with a different algorithm.

```js
function main() {
  var width = 256;
  var height = 256;
  var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
  var flExt = gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float");
  // you should always check for this unless you want confused users
  if (!flExt) {
    alert("no floating point textures available on your system");
    return;
  }

  // the algoritm from the article requires all textures and the canvas
  // to be the same size
  gl.canvas.width = width;
  gl.canvas.height = height;


  // template literals or script tags are way easier than arrays of strings
  var vertSrc = `
attribute vec4 position;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = position;
}
`;  
  var waveFragSrc = `
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D currentSourceMap;
uniform sampler2D previousResultMap;

uniform float damp;
uniform vec2 textureSize;

void main(void) {
  vec2 onePixel = 1. / textureSize;

  // this only works because we're drawing a quad the size of the texture
  // normally I'd pass in texture coords
  vec2 xy = gl_FragCoord.xy / textureSize;

  vec4 n = 
    (texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(-1, 0)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(-2, 0)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(+1, 0)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(+2, 0)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2( 0,-1)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2( 0,-2)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2( 0,+1)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2( 0,+2)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(-1,-1)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(+1,-1)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(-1,+1)) +
     texture2D(currentSourceMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(+1,+1))
    ) / 6.0 - texture2D(previousResultMap, xy);
   gl_FragColor = n - n / damp;

}

`;

  // need another shader to draw the result texture to the screen
  var displaceFragSrc = `
precision highp float;

uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform sampler2D waveMap;
uniform sampler2D backgroundImage;
uniform float fudge;

// this code assumes the wavemap and the image and the destination
// are all the same resolution
void main() {
   vec2 onePixel = 1. / resolution;

   // this only works because we're drawing a quad the size of the texture
   // normally I'd pass in texture coords
   vec2 xy = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution;

   float xDiff = (texture2D(waveMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(1, 0)) -
                  texture2D(waveMap, xy)).r;
   float yDiff = (texture2D(waveMap, xy + onePixel * vec2(0, 1)) -
                  texture2D(waveMap, xy)).r;

   gl_FragColor = texture2D(
      backgroundImage, xy + onePixel * vec2(xDiff, yDiff) * fudge);
}

`;
  
  var pntVertSrc = `
uniform vec2 position;
uniform float pointSize;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
  gl_PointSize = pointSize; 
}
`;  
  var pntFragSrc = `
precision mediump float;

void main(void) {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1);
}
`;  
  

  // use some boilerplate. I'm too lazy to type all the code for looking
  // up uniforms and setting them when a tiny piece of code can hide all
  // that for me. Look up the library if it's not clear that `setUniforms`
  // does lots of `gl.uniformXXX` etc...

  // also Use **MUST** look up the attribute locations or assign them with
  // gl.bindAttribLocation **BEFORE** linking otherwise your code
  // is not portable and may not match across programs. This boilerplate
  // calls gl.bindAttributeLocation for the names passed in the 3rd argument
  var waveProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(
    gl, [vertSrc, waveFragSrc], ["position"]);
  var displaceProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(
    gl, [vertSrc, displaceFragSrc], ["position"]);
  var pntProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(
    gl, [pntVertSrc, pntFragSrc], ["position"]);
  
  var positionLocation = 0; // see above

  // Vertex Data for rendering surface
  // no reason for 3d points when drawing 2d
  // Not using indices. It's several more lines of un-needed code
  var vertices = new Float32Array([
    -1,-1,  1,-1, -1,1,
     1,-1, -1, 1,  1,1,
  ]);

  var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  // Send texture data from tex to WebGL
  var imageTex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, imageTex);

  // since we don't have an image lets make one with a canvas 2d.
  var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
  ctx.canvas.width = width;
  ctx.canvas.height = height;
  for (var y = 0; y < width; y += 16) {
    for (var x = 0; x < height; x += 16) {
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + x / width * 256 +
                      ","    + y / height * 256 +
                      ","    + (x / 16 + y / 16) % 2 * 255 +
                      ")";
      ctx.fillRect(x, y, 16, 16);
    }
  }

  // Non-Power-of-Two Texture Dimensions
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, ctx.canvas);


  // make some data for the wave
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
  ctx.lineWidth = 30;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2,
          ctx.canvas.width / 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.stroke();

  // You can NOT use any kind of filtering on FLOAT textures unless
  // you check for and enable OES_texture_float_linear. Note that
  // no mobile devices support it as of 2017/1

  // create 3 wave textures and 3 framebuffers, prevs, current, and next
  var waves = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    var tex = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    // Non-Power-of-Two Texture Dimensions
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, ctx.canvas);

    var fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D,
                            tex, 0);
    if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) !== gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
      alert("can not render to floating point textures");
      return;
    }
    waves.push({ texture: tex, framebuffer: fb });
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001; // convert to seconds
    
    var previousWave = waves[0];
    var currentWave = waves[1];
    var nextWave = waves[2];

    // while you're only drawing 1 thing at the moment if you want to draw
    // more than one you'll need to set attributes before each draw if
    // data changes

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    
    // draw to next wave
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, nextWave.framebuffer);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);

    gl.useProgram(waveProgramInfo.program);

    // pass current and previous textures to shader
    twgl.setUniforms(waveProgramInfo, {
      currentSourceMap: currentWave.texture,
      previousResultMap: previousWave.texture,
      textureSize: [width, height],
      damp: 40,
    });

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    
    // draw dot to next wave add waves
    gl.useProgram(pntProgramInfo.program);
    
    twgl.setUniforms(pntProgramInfo, {
      position: [ Math.sin(time * 0.71), Math.cos(time) ],
      pointSize: 8,
    });
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);

    // draw to canvas
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    gl.useProgram(displaceProgramInfo.program);

    // pass in the next wave to the displacement shader
    twgl.setUniforms(displaceProgramInfo, {
      waveMap: nextWave.texture,
      backgroundImage: imageTex,
      resolution: [gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height],
      fudge: 100,
    });

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    // swap the buffers. 
    var temp = waves[0];
    waves[0] = waves[1];
    waves[1] = waves[2];
    waves[2] = temp;
    
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/2.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. To set framebuffer to null, syntax would be `gl.bindFrameBuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null)`? One of my problems has been that finding documentation specific to WebGL is hard. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/bindFramebuffer) has been helpful, but it doesn't specify how to unbind.

Comment: Yes, `gl.bindFrameBuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null)` is correct. The [link](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing-continued.html) I posted above goes over that a little. Btw googling "WebGL ripple" brings up several good examples